# How to know when user unselects text if clicking in previously active selection?

Tags: javascript, html, getselection

I'm working on a small text editing feature where I need to know when a user selects/unselects text so I can display available options accordingly. Ex: when text is selected, you can create a link, make it bold, etc. If no text is selected, those options are not displayed at all.

I use `window.getSelection()` on the `mouseup` and `keyup`events and then check the value of the `isCollapsed` property to see if there is an active selection or not. It works, but not in every case. Here are some steps to reproduce using this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0qqbaqo4/

**This works**

1. Select some text.
2. Unselect it by clicking anywhere else in the text *outside* of the current selection.
3. The result should be "There is an active selection : false".

**This does not work**

1. Select some text.
2. Unselect it by clicking anywhere *inside* the current selection.
3. The result should be "There is an active selection : false", but it will actually still be true.

This happens for me in Chrome 36 and Firefox 31 on Mac OS. I didn't test yet in other browsers.

I thought maybe on `mouseup` the text selection is *still* active and I should wait for some other event to fire, but I didn't find anything.

Any help would be great, thanks :)

Comment: Can't you use the onblur event ?

Comment: No, because by clicking in the active selection, you never leave that element, you only change your caret's position. Therefore there is no blur event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked my way around this by making sure any selection is removed on `mousedown` using the `removeAllRanges()` function. Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/0qqbaqo4/.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the event isn't getting fired at the right time. So when you're testing the selection state, the deselection event isn't gaurenteed to be resolved yet.

One simple way to manage this is to have a delayed function call, using setTimeout(fn,delay). One standard method is to delay the function by 0ms, which basically means "after all currently executing functions are done":

```
$('.editable').on('mouseup keyup', function(e){
   var selection = window.getSelection();

   setTimeout(function() {
       $('#result').text('There is an active selection : ' +           
                         !selection.isCollapsed);
   }, 0);
});
```

There may be an event triggered by jQuery that always gets triggered after the resolution, but I find the delayed response often works better without as much reading. ;-)

See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/0qqbaqo4/2/

Comment: I'm not sure why this is voted down ... the jsfiddle does what question asker wants, yes? I think there may be confusion from others about what he is asking.